# How to search within the area on the map?

Tags: macos, maps

If I open Apple Maps on my Mac, find my way to a city where I'm going to pick someone up in a few days, and then do a search for "Fast Food" (so I can find a convenient meeting place nearest to a given junction of 2 highways), Apple Maps very annoyingly searches *near **me*** instead of (more logically) near the area on the map.

It's hard to believe the designers at Apple are so out-of-touch that they have not ever thought that someone would want to search *the area displayed on the map*, so it seems like there must be some way to do this.

How can I search for things in the area shown in the map?

NOTE: the behavior of Apple Maps (on macOS) seems to currently be different from when I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop a pin at that highway junction and that you click on "Fast-Foods" in the Search Nearby section, it will automatically show the Fast-Foods around that pin. You can't search for things on your screen for now but you can around a pin.

[image: Screenshot of a highway junction]

Comment: Thanks for finding that!  (I thought there must be a way, even if it was not intuitive.)

Comment: @iconoclast You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 4):

It appears that if you click a search result with the caption "Search Nearby," it will search in your area.

However, after doing the search you can adjust the viewport and the search will update automatically to the new viewport.